# What is the term(s) used to describe programming language syntax?

Tags: programming-languages

Is there an exact/correct term to describe this difference between the syntax/constructs of programming langauges e.g VB6 with its (if ... else ... endif) and C# with its curly braces for conditional statements.

I'm using VB6 syntax and C# as examples since I'm more familiar with their syntax.

For example, Visual Basic 6's syntax uses a more verbose, natural language like structure.

```
If (id = 0) Then
    id = MyObject.Add(Me)
Else
    Call MyObject.Update(Me)
End If
```

while C# has more concise syntax like:

```
if (id == 0)
{
    id = MyObject.Add(this);
}
else
{
    MyObject.Update(this);
}
```

Conciseness? Natural languageness? Or is there a more "scientific" word for describing syntax?

Comment: Is it just me or does the "verbose" syntax take up less actual space than the "concise" syntax above?

Comment: In terms of number of lines, yes, but in terms of number of characters typed, maybe no :P

Comment: @JUSTMYcorrectOPINION I think it's just matter of style. I have checked some online compiler, and you can write C# code in 5 lines too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for the word "[terse](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/terse)", as in the opposite of verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax seems to be described in terms of what it most resembles, C#'s syntax is based off of C syntax, Lisp is based off of parentheses, Basic is influenced by Fortran etc. I found this table pretty interesting http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28syntax%29#Blocks

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link, was looking for the exact word to categorize/classify the languages though.